# How to define an array of string and number or a tuple in immutable.js

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

In typescript I can define an array of a number and string like this:

```
type A = [number, string]
```

I decided to use Immutable.js now how do I define this type using an Immutable List.

Something like this:

```
import { List } from 'immutable';

type A = List<number, string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use union:

```js
import { List } from 'immutable';

type A = List<number | string>

const a: A = List(['a', 1] as const)
```